# Printing JSON string does not show escaped characters correctly

Tags: java, json

When I print the JSON string, it prints out the backslash and character instead of a new line/tab/escaped character. The JSON is provided by Twitter and I would like to print it without the backslash. Is there a way to do it without having to use replace?

Prints:

```
a\na
```

instead of:

```
a
a
```

Comment: I am not sure but you can try org.json library to convert it into Json object ,`JSONObject js=new JSONObject("your string")`.The condition is your string should be json

Answer (score 0):

use **replace(char oldChar, char newChar)** -method.

for example:

```
object.replace("\", "");
// object is just an example variable of a parsed JSON.
```

This replaces all occurences of oldChar with newChar.
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wanted without "replace"?

Answer (score 0):

Use **JSON.parse**

```
var farid = {"data":"{\n \"myTask\" : [\n \"eating\", \n \"Sport\"]}" }
JSON.parse(farid.data)
```

The **Output** will show like this

[image]